# Find the region of convergence of the series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Please tell me how to find the region of convergence of following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

I applied the ratio test for this and got

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{-z^2}{(2n+1)(2n)}\right|= 0 $$
After this ...what should I do?

Comment: This is expansion of $\sin z$.

Comment: After this you say the convergence redius is $\infty$ and the series is converge everywhere.

Comment: @ user 108128    Are "Radius of convergence" and "Region of convergence" same?

Comment: The first is in $\mathbb{R}$ and the second is for $\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: OMG....Is that so.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that limit is indeed $0$, for whatever value of $z$, the series converges always. That is, the radius of convergence is $+\infty$.

Comment: @ Jose    Are "Radius of convergence" and "Region of convergence" same?

Comment: @Buddhike No. The radius of convergence is either $+\infty$ or a number $R\in[0,+\infty)$. Given a power series centered at $a$ (your $a$ is $0$), the region of convergence $C$ is the set of numbers $z$ at which the series converges. The number $R$ is the only number such that$$D_R(a)\subset C\subset\overline{D_R(a)}.$$In your case, $R=+\infty$ and therefore $C=\mathbb C$.

Comment: @ Jose     I did not know about that. Thank you so much

Comment: @Buddhike If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I'm new to this site. Can you tell me how to do that

Comment: @Buddhike Click on the ✓  below the downvote button.

Comment: I found it. and I marked it as a accepted one

Comment: @Buddhike Thank you. If a better answer appears later, you can always change your mind and mark that one as the accepted one.